# Can Selenium test my app for Mobile Safari and Android browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, android, selenium, ios-simulator, mobile-safari

I need to test, with Selenium or a similar automated testing tool, how my webapp behaves on iPhone's Mobile Safari and on Android browser. How can I do that?

I usually test my app by hand setting Safari 5 with User Agent = "Mobile Safari", I used iPhoney as well but it's too buggy IMO.